# Camera rotation bug

Tags: java, camera

this uses the lwjgl library.

in this 3D engine, I created a camera, it moves around fine, but the rotation is really bad. First off, left and right move diagonally down left or right, and up and down make the object stretch.

all of my rotation code to do with the camera:

```
public Vector3f rotate(float angle, Vector3f axis)
    {
        float sinHalfAngle = (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle / 2));
        float cosHalfAngle = (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle / 2));

        float rX = axis.getX() * sinHalfAngle;
        float rY = axis.getY() * sinHalfAngle;
        float rZ = axis.getZ() * sinHalfAngle;
        float rW = cosHalfAngle;

        Quaternion rotation = new Quaternion(rX, rY, rZ, rW);
        Quaternion conjugate = rotation.conjugate();

        Quaternion w = rotation.mul(this).mul(conjugate);

        x = w.getX();
        y = w.getY();
        z = w.getZ();


        return this;
    }
```

can't remember if this has to do with rotation, but it's for the camera

```
public Matrix4f ititProjection(float fov, float width, float height, float zNear, float zFar)
    {   
        float ar = width/height;
        float tanHalfFOV = (float)Math.tan(Math.toRadians(fov / 2));
        float zRange = zNear - zFar;

        m[0][0] = 1.0f / (tanHalfFOV * ar); m[0][1] = 0;                  m[0][2] = 0;                      m[0][3] = 0;
        m[1][0] = 0;                        m[1][1] =  1.0f / tanHalfFOV; m[1][2] = 0;                      m[1][3] = 0;
        m[2][0] = 0;                        m[2][1] = 0;                  m[2][2] = (-zNear - zFar)/zRange; m[2][3] = 2 * zFar * zNear / zRange;
        m[3][0] = 0;                        m[3][1] = 0;                  m[3][2] = 1;                      m[3][3] = 0;

        return this;
    }

    public Matrix4f initCamera(Vector3f forward, Vector3f up)
    {
        Vector3f f = forward;
        f.normalize();

        Vector3f r = up;
        r.normalize();
        r = r.cross(f);

        Vector3f u = f.cross(r);

        m[0][0] = r.getX(); m[0][1] = r.getY(); m[0][2] = r.getZ(); m[0][3] = 0;
        m[1][0] = u.getX(); m[1][1] = u.getY(); m[1][2] = r.getZ(); m[1][3] = 0;
        m[2][0] = f.getX(); m[2][1] = f.getY(); m[2][2] = f.getZ(); m[2][3] = 0;
        m[3][0] = 0;        m[3][1] = 0;        m[3][2] = 0;        m[3][3] = 1;

            return this;
    }
```

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Comment: Code seems to be Java. I detect an error just in reading your code initCamera, m[1][2]=u.getZ(); and not r.getZ();